# how can I complete correctly ansible playbook to get info what i want

Tags: ansible

I'm very new with ansible so I need help to complete my first ansible playbook
I need to get the results from file created below logs directory.
I also need to input container name which is migrated to find results file named with container and starts with 1 and 3 (2 results of files need)
can't find which part got wrong.
Please help me out
Thank you in advance.

```
---

- name : find the results for migration ended
  hosts: newmigservers
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "what is the container name?"
        echo: yes
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        container: "{{ result.user_input }}"
    - debug:
        var: container

    - name: find where the container is
      shell: "grep -lr '{{ container }}'"
      args:
        chdir: "logs/"
      register: grep_output

- name: cat 1,3 file for the results
  command: cat {{ grep_output }}
  register: results
```

```
PLAY [find the results for migration ended] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

 

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [1.1.1.1]

ok: [2.2.2.2]

ok: [3.3.3.3]

 

TASK [pause] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

[pause]

what is the container name?:

ok: [1.1.1.1]

 

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [1.1.1.1]

fatal: [2.2.2.2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'result' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/amber/results.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n register: result\n - set_fact:\n ^ here\n"}

fatal: [3.3.3.3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'result' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/amber/results.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n register: result\n - set_fact:\n ^ here\n"}

 

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

ok: [1.1.1.1] => {

"container": "amber_test_file_size.txt"

}

 

TASK [find where the container is] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

skipping: [2.2.2.2]

 

TASK [cat 1,3 file for the results] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

skipping: [3.3.3.3.]

to retry, use: --limit @/home/amber/results.retry

 

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

1.1.1.1 : ok=4 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0

2.2.2.2 : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1

3.3.3.3 : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pause runs only once for the play batch, causing only the first server in the batch (`1.1.1.1` in my case) to pick the variable.

You can workaround this by adding serial to your playbook as below:

```yaml
---

- name : find the results for migration ended
  hosts: newmigservers
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "what is the container name?"
        echo: yes
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        container: "{{ result.user_input }}"
    - debug:
        var: container
```

Comment: Do you need to enter the same `container` name for each server or are they different ?

Comment: Absolutely not. Remember each server will have it the container name that is used for it its own facts.

Comment: not what ? :) not the same name or not different ?

Comment: Not the same name.

Comment: thank you for the answer. after adding serial 1, I could play 3 servers but after setting var to container, task for grep and cat are skipped. i need to play both task with variable with container I put.. do you have any idea for this?

Comment: i think you can use a block/rescue to group the grep and the cat tasks.  
another thing: remember cat wont show you anything, use debug instead.